# What the best way to use command binding under Microsoft.Toolkit.MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I'm using Microsoft.Toolkit.MVVM, in [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/relaycommand)
we can use binding `Button` command like:

```
<Button
    Content="Click me!"
    Command="{Binding ButtonClickCommand}"/>
```

But for `ListView`, I have to write like with `Behaviors`, this code is to long:

```
<ListView>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListView>
```

So why can't use below code instead? This is simple, but not working.

```
<ListView SelectionChanged={Binding SelectionChangedCommand}/>
```

Comment: They are different types. `Command` property is of `ICommand` type, but the `SelectionChanged` property should be matched with an Event Handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the simple answer is the type of the object
in button Command is ICommand and in the ListView the SelectionChanged is an event and not ICommand , this why you need to use eventTrigger which is an "addon"

if you look at it from MVVM perspective the button is here to bind a command the ListView has SelectedItems collection that you can bind to and not the event , but that's more of a choice you need to make (I think that your code looks fine once you are used to it)